# Question about sign

Tags: current, simulation, current-measurement

I need to answer this question using PSpice:
[image]
[image]

It seems it's -15mA, BUT in the exercise, the current source is < (I understand it's + < -)

in Pspice I set it to < as well, but there is - < + in the schema.

Is it 15mA or -15mA?

Comment: Solving through probability calculation: There are two answers 15mA, one for 5mA and one for 10. Chances are that one of the 15mA answers is correct because you are probably not the only one confused about the sign. Then there are three negative answers and only one positive. ... Probability says it is the negative answer as most students that do the calculation wrong may have the sign correct. I'd say -15mA, not looking at the circuit at all ;o)  Actually I am not sure what current you are looking for anyway, so you may want to improve your question on that.

Comment: And why did R2 move positions?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is "what current thru L?" then the answer is clearly -5mA.

15mA flows thru the combination of 1k5 // (2k+1k) and because 2k+1k is twice 1k5 then two-thirds of the current flows through the 1k5 with the remainder (5mA) flowing through 2k+1k. This current also flows backwards through the inductor (0 ohms) therefore it is -5mA.

The capacitor, the 20V source and the 1k resistor to the left of the current source are totally irrelevent to answering this question.

If the question is something else then I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must correctly draw circuit to get correct answer from pspice.

**Deleted wrong explanation. My mistake, sorry. Correct answer is posted by Andy.**

Comment: Sir you are a gentleman